# Open ipynb file from the colab disk

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a file on Google Collab `x.ipynb` and I would like to open it. Simple

```
%run x.ipynb
```

would run it but inside a single cell.

Instead, I would like to have the same effect as I uploaded that file:

[image]

Which opens a new colab notebook for me. 
I searched Code snippets "open" but haven't found what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, connect to your Google Drive files --

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then, copy the notebook into Drive --

```
cp x.ipynb /content/drive/My\ Drive/
```

Then, use `xattr` to obtain the file identifier --

```
!xattr -p 'user.drive.id' /content/drive/My\ Drive/x.ipynb
```

Then, you can open that notebook like so:

`https://colab.research.google.com/drive/...drive file ID goes here...`

Comment: what is the "user.drive.id"?

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append('models/research')

sys.path.append('models/research/object_detection')
```

Another way,

You can upload the notebook to google drive first, then open it from there.

1. go to drive.google.com
2. go into directory “Colab Notebooks”
3. choose “New” > File upload
4. After uploading, click the new file
5. Choose “Open with Colaboratory” at the top

Comment: The "Open with Colaboratory" doesn't show for me. Where is it?

Answer (score 0):

go to drive.google.com

go into directory “Colab Notebooks” (where you have your ipynb file)
Note: I originally created my project in Colab

The ipynb file should have the "colab" icon with the two-loops in front of it.

Double-click on it:

It will open up in a new Colab tab